# Work around average behaviour with nulls

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, null

I have two tables:

- Product (PK product_id, brand, model)
- Order (PK invoice_id, customer_name, customer_email, FK product_id)

I am trying to find the product(s) whose number of times that product is sold is closest to the average number of times a product is sold.

The problem is as far as I know the `AVG` function ignores NULL values when it calculates the average. So if a product has never been sold before, it won't be included in the average, but it should be included for my calculation to be correct. A null should be counted as zero to lower the average.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count `NULL` like 0 when calculating an average, use

```
avg(coalesce(colname, 0))
```

`coalesce` will return the first of its arguments that is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an outer join so that products without orders are also counted.

You can calculate the average within the same statement by using a window function.

Something along the lines:

```
select *, (num_orders / average_orders) * 100 as pct
from (  
  select p.product_id, 
         count(o.invoice_id) as num_orders,
         avg(count(o.invoice_id)) over () as average_orders
  from product p
    left join "Order" o on o.product_id = p.product_id
  group by p.product_id
) t
```

`count(o.invoice_id)` will yield 0 for products that have no order as the  null values are ignored and the invoice_id will be null for those products (as no order exists)

You could then sort by the percentage to find those that are closest to the average.